# Is there a way to fix the issue of there being rows that has NA values for all of its attributes and NA for its rowname?

Tags: r

I am trying to store all rows with NA for my columns Math_G1, Math_G2 and Math_G3 into a dataset variable. However when I do this, there are additional rows that pops up which have NA as values throughout all its attributes including its row number (eg. NA.1, NA.2 ...) How do I fix this?

I have already tried to use the c() function to attempt to filter out all these results but these rows are still there, in addition to this, i have also used the which() function but they are still there.

Here is my code :

```
dat <- read.csv(file = "final merged.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=c("NA", "NULL")) 

dat_small <- dat[c("age","traveltime","studytime",
                       "failures","famrel","freetime","goout","Dalc","Walc",
                       "health","absences","Math_G1","Math_G2","Math_G3","Por_G1","Por_G2","Por_G3","DoubleSub")]

sample_size <- 500

all_set <- sample(1:length(dat[,1]),sample_size,replace = F)

dat <- dat_small[all_set,]

index_na_math <- which(is.na(c(dat$Math_G1,dat$Math_G2,dat$Math_G3)))
index_na_por <- which(is.na(c(dat$Por_G1,dat$Por_G2,dat$Por_G3)))
index_na_both <- c(index_na_math,index_na_por)

#each row of my dataset helps define a specific student
#portugese and math are subjects that students within the dataset takes

dat_purepor <- dat[which(index_na_math),] #students who takes only portugese
dat_puremath <- dat[c(index_na_por),] # students who takes only math 
dat_math <- dat[c(-index_na_math),] #students who takes math + students who take both
dat_por <- dat[c(-index_na_por),] #students who take portugese + students who take both
dat_both <- dat[c(-index_na_both),] #students who takes both math and portugese 

dat_purepor 
dat_puremath
```

I expected the output to be filtered according to my conditions but without any rows with NA as the values for all its columns so I don't understand why the final results return NA.

Here is a preview of the dataset dat_small:

```
> dat_small
    age traveltime studytime failures famrel freetime goout Dalc Walc health absences Math_G1 Math_G2 Math_G3 Por_G1 Por_G2 Por_G3 DoubleSub
1    18          2         2        0      4        3     4    1    1      3        6       5       6       6     13     13     13         1
2    17          1         2        0      5        3     3    1    1      3        4       5       5       6     15     15     15         1
3    15          1         2        3      4        3     2    2    3      3       10       7       8      10     10     12     13         1
4    15          1         3        0      3        2     2    1    1      5        2      15      14      15     14     14     14         1
5    16          1         2        0      4        3     2    1    2      5        4       6      10      10     13     13     13         1
6    16          1         2        0      5        4     2    1    2      5       10      15      15      15     10     13     13         1
7    16          1         2        0      4        4     4    1    1      3        0      12      12      11     14     14     16         1
8    17          2         2        0      4        1     4    1    1      1        6       6       5       6     12     13     13         1
9    15          1         2        0      4        2     2    1    1      1        0      16      18      19     13     17     17         1
10   15          1         2        0      5        5     1    1    1      5        0      14      15      15      9     10     11         1
11   15          1         2        0      3        3     3    1    2      2        0      10       8       9     15     15     15         1
12   15          3         3        0      5        2     2    1    1      4        4      10      12      12     10     12     13         1
13   15          1         1        0      4        3     3    1    3      5        2      14      14      14     13     14     15         1
14   15          2         2        0      5        4     3    1    2      3        2      10      10      11     14     14     14         1
15   15          1         3        0      4        5     2    1    1      3        0      14      16      16     11     12     14         1
16   16          1         1        0      4        4     4    1    2      2        4      14      14      14      9      8      9         1
17   16          1         3        0      3        2     3    1    2      2        6      13      14      14     10     10     16         1
18   16          3         2        0      5        3     2    1    1      4        4       8      10      10     11     11     11         1
19   17          1         1        3      5        5     5    2    4      5       16       6       5       5     10     13     13         1
20   16          1         1        0      3        1     3    1    3      5        4       8      10      10     14     14     14         1
21   15          1         2        0      4        4     1    1    1      1        0      13      14      15      9      8     10         1
22   15          1         1        0      5        4     2    1    1      5        0      12      15      15     10     13     13         1
23   16          1         2        0      4        5     1    1    3      5        2      15      15      16     11     10     11         1
24   16          2         2        0      5        4     4    2    4      5        0      13      13      12     14     14     14         1
25   15          1         3        0      4        3     2    1    1      5        2      10       9       8     10     11     10         1
26   16          1         1        2      1        2     2    1    3      5       14       6       9       8     13     13     13         1
27   15          1         1        0      4        2     2    1    2      5        2      12      12      11     12     11     12         1
28   15          1         1        0      2        2     4    2    4      1        4      15      16      15     14     12     12         1
29   16          1         2        0      5        3     3    1    1      5        4      11      11      11     10     10      1         1
30   16          1         2        0      4        4     5    5    5      5       16      10      12      11      9     12     12         1
31   15          1         2        0      5        4     2    3    4      5        0       9      11      12      9     10     11         1
32   15          2         2        0      4        3     1    1    1      5        0      17      16      17     14     14     16         1
33   15          1         2        0      4        5     2    1    1      5        0      17      16      16     14     14     16         1
34   15          1         2        0      5        3     2    1    1      2        0       8      10      12     10     13     13         1
35   16          1         1        0      5        4     3    1    1      5        0      12      14      15      9     12     12         1
36   15          2         1        0      3        5     1    1    1      5        0       8       7       6     14     13     12         1
37   15          1         3        0      5        4     3    1    1      4        2      15      16      18     14     14     16         1
38   16          2         3        0      2        4     3    1    1      5        7      15      16      15      9      9      8         1
39   15          1         3        0      4        3     2    1    1      5        2      12      12      11     14     13     12         1
40   15          1         1        0      4        3     1    1    1      2        8      14      13      13     14     13     12         1
41   16          2         2        1      3        3     3    1    2      3       25       7      10      11     13     13     13         1
42   15          1         1        0      5        4     3    2    4      5        8      12      12      12     10     13     13         1
43   15          1         2        0      4        3     3    1    1      5        2      19      18      18      9     12     12         1
44   15          1         1        0      5        4     1    1    1      1        0       8       8      11     10     13     13         1
45   16          2         2        1      4        3     3    2    2      5       14      10      10       9     11     11     11         1
46   15          1         2        0      5        2     2    1    1      5        8       8       8       6     12     11     12         1
47   16          1         2        0      2        3     5    1    4      3       12      11      12      11     10     11     11         1
48   16          1         4        0      4        2     2    1    1      2        4      19      19      20     14     14     16         1
49   15          1         2        0      4        3     3    2    2      5        2      15      15      14     10     13     13         1
50   15          1         2        1      4        4     4    1    1      3        2       7       7       7     15     15     15         1
51   16          3         2        0      4        3     3    2    3      4        2      12      13      13     13     13     13         1
52   15          1         2        0      4        3     3    1    1      5        2      11      13      13     16     14     16         1
53   15          2         1        1      5        5     5    3    4      5        6      11      11      10     14     14     16         1
54   15          1         1        0      3        3     4    2    3      5        0       8      10      11     11     12     13         1
55   15          1         1        0      5        3     4    4    4      1        6      10      13      13     13     12     13         1
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 889 rows ]
```

Here is a preview of what happens when i run the dat_puremath dataset.

```
> dat_puremath
      age traveltime studytime failures famrel freetime goout Dalc Walc health absences Math_G1 Math_G2 Math_G3 Por_G1 Por_G2 Por_G3 DoubleSub
918    15          2         4        0      4        4     2    2    3      3       12      16      16      16     NA     NA     NA         0
931    16          1         2        3      2        3     3    2    2      4        5       7       7       7     NA     NA     NA         0
933    16          1         2        0      3        3     4    1    1      4        0      12      13      14     NA     NA     NA         0
935    16          1         1        0      4        5     2    1    1      5       20      13      12      12     NA     NA     NA         0
927    16          2         2        0      3        4     4    1    4      5        2      13      13      11     NA     NA     NA         0
929    17          1         2        0      5        3     3    1    1      3        0       8       8       9     NA     NA     NA         0
942    17          1         3        0      3        3     2    2    2      3        3      11      11      11     NA     NA     NA         0
928    16          1         2        0      1        2     2    1    2      1       14      12      13      12     NA     NA     NA         0
936    17          1         3        0      3        2     3    1    1      4        4      10       9       9     NA     NA     NA         0
939    17          1         4        0      5        2     2    1    2      5        0      17      17      18     NA     NA     NA         0
941    17          1         2        0      4        2     2    1    1      3       12      11       9       9     NA     NA     NA         0
937    17          1         2        0      5        4     5    1    2      5        4      10       9      11     NA     NA     NA         0
925    16          1         2        0      4        4     2    1    1      3        0      14      14      14     NA     NA     NA         0
938    17          1         3        0      4        3     3    1    1      3        6      13      12      12     NA     NA     NA         0
921    15          1         3        0      4        2     2    1    1      5        2       9      11      11     NA     NA     NA         0
943    17          1         3        0      4        4     3    1    1      5        7      12      14      14     NA     NA     NA         0
NA     NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.1   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.2   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.3   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.4   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.5   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.6   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.7   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.8   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.9   NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.10  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.11  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.12  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.13  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.14  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.15  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.16  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.17  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.18  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.19  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.20  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.21  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.22  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.23  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.24  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.25  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.26  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.27  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.28  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.29  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.30  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
NA.31  NA         NA        NA       NA     NA       NA    NA   NA   NA     NA       NA      NA      NA      NA     NA     NA     NA        NA
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I have also checked the original dataset and that doesn't have any rows with NA across its entire spectrum of attributes

Comment: What is dat_small? Can’t see what you are trying to index to

Comment: @e.matt thank you for mentioning it , I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When indexing,  using `is.na(c(dat$Math_G1,dat$Math_G2,dat$Math_G3))` creates an array of length `3*nrow(dat)`, so when applying the indices it does not behave as expected once past the index number `nrow(dat)`.

Try the following

```
index_na_math <- (is.na(dat$Math_G1) | is.na(dat$Math_G2) | is.na(dat$Math_G3))
```

similarly for the other one, and then

```
index_na_both <- index_na_math | index_na_por
# or depending what you mean by 'both'
index_na_both <- index_na_math & index_na_por
```

The subsetting with `dat_math <- dat[!index_na_math,]` will yield the expected result (accordingly for the others).